# Avoidy Lazy Initialization except in dozer mapping for null collections

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, dozer

```
@Override
RegistrationDto isCandidateUnfit(RegistrationDto dto) {
    Long nationId = 0L;
    if(dto.getNationMast() != null){
        nationId = dto.getNationMast().getNationId();
    }
    Registration reg = registrationRepo.findCandidateMedicalStatus(dto.getPassportNo(),nationId,
                    dto.getCivilId(), ServiceConstants.CANDIDATE_MED_STATUS_UNFIT_ID); 

    return getMapper().map(reg, RegistrationDto.class) ;
}
```

While mapping the doing dozer mapping if one caollection(appointments) is null, it throw exception failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: om.gov.moh.model.cdc.Registration.appointments

It can't be changed from Lazy to eager

```
//RegistrationDto


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class RegistrationDto extends SearchDto implements java.io.Serializable {

// Fields

private Long regId; 

@JsonIgnore
private Set<AppointmentDto> appointments = new HashSet<>(0);
private String orderStatus;


/** setters & getters **/
```

}

Comment: Which ORM are you using?

Comment: You are getting your LazyInitializationException through Dozer. Try to exclude the appointments proprety  by using this as a guide http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/exclude.html

Comment: @Turbut Alin spring orm

Comment: Had to exclude only when its null

Answer (score 2):

You have the possibility to create custom converters as shown [here](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/customconverter.html).

Create a custom converter and when you have an uninitialized collection, just set it to null or empty. You can do the check with Hibernate.isInitiliazed(Object proxy). Reference [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/Hibernate.html#isInitialized-java.lang.Object-).